# Can the rational numbers be specified as an ordered field with <order property>?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, rational-numbers

In other words, (the opposite of my question is) does there exist an ordered field which is isomorphic as (as an ordered SET) to $\mathbb{Q}$? If not, does there exist an order property which specifies $\mathbb{Q}$ among ordered fields?

For instance, the integers are the unique ordered ring whose positive elements are well-ordered. (You can replace this with 'Any set bounded below is well-ordered', to remove any reference to the ring structure). The reals are the unique ordered field with the least upper bound property.

My first thought for a counterexample would be finite real algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ which inherit an ordering as subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. These are at least countable, but I can't think of how I would construct an isomorphism.

Comment: To build the isomorphism, you need only go [back and forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method).

Comment: As the posts already here show, any countable linearly-ordered field is going to be order-isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$, but they may not be field-isomorphic. But you can characterize $\Bbb Q$ by an algebraic property: $\Bbb Q$ is the smallest field of characteristic $0$. Since every linearly-ordered field has characteristic $0$, every linearly-ordered field contains a subfield isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$. This isomorphism even extends (or restricts) to the ordering, thus you can also call $\Bbb Q$ the smallest linearly-ordered field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ is a field and a countable dense linear order.  All countable dense linear orders without endpoints are order isomorphic.  That doesn't say there is a nice way to define the isomorphism by a formula.

Comment: do you have a reference for this fact?

Comment: @breeden:  the reference by Quinn Culver shows the construction.